# Given $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+x^2y+xy^2$ ,find $f'(x)$

Tags: calculus

This question has already been asked but the solution was not satisfactory

Suppose $f$ is a function satisfying the equation
$$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+x^2y+xy^2$$ for all real numbers $x$ and $y$
Suppose also that
$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=1$

Find $f'(x)$

By using the definition of derivative,I obtained $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$

How will I get $f'(x)$?

Answer (score 6):

The definition of the derivative is
$$
f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}
$$
Using the property we've been given about $f$, we get
$$
\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \frac{f(x) + f(h) + x^2h + xh^2 - f(x)}{h}\\
= \frac{f(h)}{h} + x^2 + xh
$$
This gives
$$
f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}\\
= \lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{f(h)}h + x^2 + xh\right)\\
= 1 + x^2
$$